Why is default volume for individual streams being ignored? (wireplumber / pipewire)
Volume for individual streams (applications) keeps defaulting (being reset) to 46% (0.46), whenever applications are closed and reopened.
This is independent to the internal volume control to whatever application (Chrome, mpv, etc.), which are all at 100%.
wpctl get-volume 81
Volume: 0.46

wpctl get-volume 84
Volume: 0.46

wpctl get-volume 88
Volume: 0.46

This is even though Output of wpctl settings node.stream.default-playback-volume is set to 1.0, not to 0.46.
- Name: node.stream.default-playback-volume
  Desc: The default volume for playback nodes
  Type: Float
  Default: 1.0  [Min: 0.0, Max: 1.0]
  Value: 1.0

It happens only on Budgie (Ubuntu 24.04) not on the default Ubuntu session, and only with USB speakers, not with internal speakers.
I have posted the original issue on Budgie discourse, but is there a way to set default volume for indivdual applications (not master volume) from 46% to 100%, as a workaround?
wpctl status:

PipeWire 'pipewire-0' [1.0.5, user@home, cookie:301889472]
 └─ Clients:
        32. WirePlumber                         [1.0.5, user@home, pid:1380]
        36. pipewire                            [1.0.5, user@home, pid:1382]
        46. WirePlumber [export]                [1.0.5, user@home, pid:1380]
        57. GNOME Volume Control Media Keys     [1.0.5, user@home, pid:1661]
        58. Budgie Volume Control               [1.0.5, user@home, pid:1818]
        59. Budgie Volume Control               [1.0.5, user@home, pid:1818]
        60. Budgie Volume Control               [1.0.5, user@home, pid:1818]
        61. budgie-wm                           [1.0.5, user@home, pid:1786]
        62. linphone                            [1.0.5, user@home, pid:2137]
        63. plank                               [1.0.5, user@home, pid:2151]
        64. Chromium input                      [1.0.5, user@home, pid:2958]
        65. Terminal                            [1.0.5, user@home, pid:3130]
        66. Mutter                              [1.0.5, user@home, pid:1786]
        75. wpctl                               [1.0.5, user@home, pid:3591]
        79. mpv                                 [1.0.5, user@home, pid:3566]

Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │      50. Built-in Audio                      [alsa]
 │      82. USB Audio                           [alsa]
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │      54. Built-in Audio Analog Stereo        [vol: 0.80]
 │  *   67. USB Audio Analog Stereo             [vol: 0.58]
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │      55. Built-in Audio Analog Stereo        [vol: 1.00]
 │  
 ├─ Filters:
 │  
 **└─ Streams:
        81. mpv                                                         
             78. output_FL       > USB Audio:playback_FL    [active]
             80. output_FR       > USB Audio:playback_FR    [active]
        84. Chromium                                                    
             70. output_FR       > USB Audio:playback_FR    [active]
             83. output_FL       > USB Audio:playback_FL    [active]
        88. io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid                        
             89. output_FL       > USB Audio:playback_FL    [active]
             90. output_FR       > USB Audio:playback_FR    [active]**


Video
 ├─ Devices:
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │  
 ├─ Filters:
 │  
 └─ Streams:

Settings
 └─ Default Configured Devices:
         0. Audio/Sink    alsa_output.usb-10ae_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo
 Blockquote

UPDATE
I upgraded wireplumber with the debian experimental package (0.5.2), to use wpctl settings, which is not implemented in yet in the ubuntu package (0.4.7).
I made this ugly workaround, which I have set to a keyboard hotkey, which I press after starting to play an audio file:
for i in $(wpctl status | grep -A 10 Streams | cut -c 9,10); do wpctl set-volume $i 90%; done


take the first 10 lines after the subheading 'Streams' wpctl status | grep -A 10 Streams,
for each line take only the 9th and 10th characters cut -c 9,10, which on some lines, will be the ID number of a stream;
for each, then set the volume to 90%, wpctl set-volume $i 90%

Better suggestions, or an answer to the original problem (why default volume is 0.46 even though it is set to 1.0), would be appreciated.

Fixed in wireplumber 0.5.3.
Bug report: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/wireplumber/-/issues/655
